# Carbon set location Laravel

Tags: php, date, laravel-5, php-carbon, locate

I am trying to localize dates to French and Arabic in my Laravel 5.4 application, but always they're still in English.

this my code :

**AppServiceProvider**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
     /**
      * The Config::get('app.locate') value: fr , ar
      */

     \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(Config::get('app.locate'));
     ....
    }
}
```

**View**

```
{{ $user->created_at->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y') }}
```

The result is always:

> "Thursday 05 October 2017"

### -----------------------------------------------------------

I try also to use the **setlocale** function like this :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ar_AR');
```

It work perfect in Frensh (fr) but not in Arabic (ar)

The result of setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');

> "Jeudi 05 octobre 2017"

The result of setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ar_AR');

> "Thursday 05 October 2017"

### -----------------------------------------------------------

I am a Mac OS user , so i check the packages languages

```
locale -a
```

I didn't found the ar_AR package, i try the **locale-gen** command but it don't work for me.

Any help please.

Comment: https://github.com/jenssegers/date

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, i will try this.

Comment: note that you're pulling `app.locate` config, you probably want `app.locale`

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble with translations, check locales installed in your system (local and production).
`locale -a` to list locales enabled.

`sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8` to install a new locale.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure` locales to publish all locale enabled.
And reboot your system.

Unfortunately the base class DateTime does not have any localization support. To begin localization support a formatLocalized($format) method was added. The implementation makes a call to strftime using the current instance timestamp. If you first set the current locale with PHP function setlocale() then the string returned will be formatted in the correct locale.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Mittwoch 21 Mai 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, '');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Wednesday 21 May 1975
```

Ref:
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, i use Mac OS and the commande **locale-gen** not found

Comment: i am not sure about mac .i have added as per documentation.hope if you google it then you will get it any commandd

Comment: I try google but i didn't found  how can i add a language pack to Mac OS

Comment: sorry i have no idea since i have not used mac

Comment: Thank you for your help dude.

Comment: no worry.hopeyou can try Bugfixer comment github repository